# Mysql NULL field and php isset?

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have data in my mysql fields which are `NULL`

But in php when getting the data into an array how come I can compare the value of it without first using php's `isset`?

Example,

```
$var = null;

if ($var == 123123) // GENERATES ERROR AS DIDN'T CHECK IF IT WAS SET FIRST
```

But in mysql

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT nullColumn FROM table_1");
$q -> execute();
$null = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($null['nullColumn'] == 2312312) // DOESN'T GENERATE ERROR EVEN THOUGH VALUE IS NULL
```

I have also used `var_dump` on the value and it returns `NULL`

Comment: why don't you want to use isset? please provide a code example so that we can understand your use case

Comment: You don't *have to* use `isset` if your value is `null`. You might be mixing something up here. Care for an illustrative code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $var = null;
>
> if ($var == 123123) // GENERATES ERROR AS DIDN'T CHECK IF IT WAS SET FIRST
> ```

This premise is false! The above code will *not* generate an error, because the variable `$var` exists.

Trying to use a variable which does *not* exist, i.e. which hasn't been declared anywhere, generates an error. Trying to use a declared variable whose value is `null` is perfectly legit.

See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's `isset` And `empty`](http://kunststube.net/isset) for an in-depth look into this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess depends on the driver. PDO fetches NULL for NULL fields. 
Don't have to use isset, use `is_null($field)` or `null === $field`